# How should I recode non-numeric categorical variables when calculating means for ANOVA?

Tags: anova, categorical-data

I have some data, where one of the columns is the Sex of the person. And it takes values M and F.

I'm calculating ANOVA by hand and to do this I need to calculate the means of each column.

Obviously non-numerical values have no concept of mean, but I could recode this column to e.g. binary. But I expect that the numerical values that I give to this column might affect the ANOVA computation, right?

Like instead of using {0,1} I could use any {p,q}.

So how should I recode these variables?

Comment: When you use anova you are testing the difference between within group means and across group means, so scaling the mean by a constant (i.e. using 10001, 10002 instead of 0,1) will not affect the results (results meaning the F-stat)

Comment: that's not how to think about it, (10002 + 10001)/2 = 10001.5 so the variance values in the sample variance will take on the form (10002-10001.5)^2 =.5^2 just like the binary case

Comment: I would read up on exactly what you are doing with ANOVA